# RecyclerView adds undesired item when deleting

Tags: sqlite, animation, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter

I have a problem when deleting an item from RecyclerView (linked with a SQLite db). After the item removal is successful, it shows the animation and then the item re-appears at the bottom (with a fancy animation too). 
When I check the database it actually removed the row.

I could solve this by creating the adapter again everytime I remove an item, but then the animation is gone.

Here is my code:

Method of the adapter:

```
public void removeItem(int position){
        db = new DBAdapter(context);
        db.open();
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        int idnota = mCursorAdapter.getCursor().getInt(0);
        db.borra_nota(idnota); //it deletes the row (delete_note)
        db.close();
    }
```

Inside my main activity:

```
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            //if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            listAdapter.removeItem(position);
            listAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, listAdapter.getItemCount());
            listAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

My initial solution (but without the animations) looked like this:

```
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            sticky = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lista_notas);
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
            sticky.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            listAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            sticky.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Of course, putting the "removeItem" and so inside the remove method of the adapter.

Any idea of how to show the animation preventing the list to show a new and actually unexistent item?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved!

The problem lied in the fact that I was deleting the row but not the CursorAdapter.

The method in my ListAdapter, now working, looks like this:

```
    public void removeItem(int position){
        db = new DBAdapter(context);
        db.open();
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        int idnota = mCursorAdapter.getCursor().getInt(0);
        db.borra_nota(idnota); //it deletes the row (delete_note)

        items = db.consulta_todos(); //select all from db again
        mCursorAdapter.changeCursor(items);
    }
```

Greetings!